# Get the string after a string from a string

Tags: php, string

what's the fastest way to get only the **important_stuff** part from a string like this:

```
bla-bla_delimiter_important_stuff
```

`_delimiter_` is always there, but the rest of the string can change.

Comment: seems to be som confusion over whether the underscores are literally there or not.  any solutions below are good.

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->afterFirst('_delimiter_')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L435) or [`s($str)->afterLast('_delimiter_')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L445) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

here:

```
$arr = explode('delimeter', $initialString);
$important = $arr[1];
```

Comment: In PHP 5.4... for this case in particular... you can do the following one liner... `$important = explode("delimeter",$initialString)[1];`

Comment: This solution doesn't work in cases where the delimiter occurs more than once.

Comment: OP hasnt even stated the desired behavior in that situation. so we have no idea if it "works"

Comment: If there is only one delimiter it might be faster to add the `limit` parameter: `explode('delimiter', $initialString, 2)` – no need for traversing after it

Comment: I suggest this to avoid warning:
$important = isset($arr[1]) ? $arr[1] : "";

Answer (score 37):

```
$result = end(explode('_delimiter_', 'bla-bla_delimiter_important_stuff'));
```

Comment: This will throw: Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference. You have to assign the explode() to a temp var.

Answer (score 8):

I like this method:

```
$str="bla-bla_delimiter_important_stuff";
$del="_delimiter_";
$pos=strpos($str, $del);
```

cutting from end of the delimiter to end of string

```
$important=substr($str, $pos+strlen($del)-1, strlen($str)-1);
```

note:

1) for substr the string start at '0' whereas for strpos & strlen takes the size of the string (starts at '1')

2) using 1 character delimiter maybe a good idea

Answer (score 6):

```
$string = "bla-bla_delimiter_important_stuff";
list($junk,$important_stufF) = explode("_delimiter_",$string);

echo $important_stuff;
> important_stuff
```

Comment: i like the use of list.  when you first had array i thought you had shown me a python-like capability of php i hadnt known!

Comment: I prefer this answer but 2 Notes. 1) When using list you need not give the `$junk` variable - `list(,$important_stufF) = explode(...)` is fine.  2) in later versions of PHP7 you can use the shorter syntax - `[,$important_stufF] = explode(...)`

Answer (score 6):

```
$importantStuff = array_pop(explode('_delimiter_', $string));
```

Comment: This will throw an `E_STRICT` error (`Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference`) as array_pop uses reference, but it still works.

Answer (score 1):

Me, being a REGEX enthusiast:

```
if (preg_match('/.*_delimiter_(.*)/', 'bla-bla_delimiter_important_stuff', $matches)) echo $matches[1];
```