# how to trim string after specific word in php?

Tags: php

I want to trim a string after a specific word. Please check what I am doing:

```
$str = "kids-story-in-chaper2.php";
$rest = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, 'in'));
```

Here I am expecting output:
-chapter2.php

But nothing work.

I want to trim after "in", I also tries

```
substr($str,11);
```

// Working but the string is dynamic so I have to trim after "in". So its failed.

Any ideas or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the string after a string from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221117/get-the-string-after-a-string-from-a-string)

Comment: I'm very surprised it doesn't give you anything. https://3v4l.org/J68tX the only problem I see is that you extract the first part of the string, not the last part as you say you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can find words and insert its position in substr function

```
$str = "kids-story-in-chaper2.php";
$separator = 'in';
$pos = strpos($str, $separator) + strlen($separator);
$rest = substr($str, $pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```html
<?php
$str = "kids-story-in-chaper2.php";
echo $str = substr($str, strpos($str, 'in-')+3);
```

[output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e120113495aa6ede1712b8cb83017cd51b73ca3)    you can check here

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that the string has only one `-in-` then you can you `explode()` the string. and take the last element using `array_pop()` or `end()`.

```
$str = "kids-story-in-chaper2.php";
$res = explode('-in-', $str);
$res = array_pop($res);
echo $res;

//output
chapter2.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
$str = "kids-story-in-chaper2.php";
$rest = end(explode('-in', $str));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "kids-story-in-chaper2.php";
$rest = substr($str, strpos($str, 'in')+2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually avoid regex as much as possible but in this case I believe regex is the best option since it will not fail if the word "in" is missing in the string as the other solutions do.
The regex will grab anything that is after the $find and save it to the $match array.

```
$str = "kids-story-in-chaper2.php";
$find = "in";
preg_match("/". preg_quote($find) . "(.*)/", $str, $match);
if(isset($match[1])) echo $match[1];
```

https://3v4l.org/Blqua